# Cannot get to 192.168.*.* addresses when using chromium with socks proxy

Tags: chrome, proxy, socks, socks5-proxy

I'm running the following command on terminal:

```
$ /usr/bin/chromium-browser --proxy-server="socks5://127.0.0.1:9050" --host-resolver-rules="MAP * ~NOTFOUND, EXCLUDE 127.0.0.1, EXCLUDE 192.168.1.106" 2>&1 >/dev/null &
```

After chromium is opened, I cannot get to `192.168.1.106:4004` at which a NodeJS app is running. Despite the fact that I've excluded `192.168.1.106` in the `--host-resolver-rules` option.

Just to double-check, I can get to `192.168.1.106:4004` when opening chromium by just running:

```
$ /usr/bin/chromium-browser 2>&1 >/dev/null &
```

Therefore, I need to modify the chromium proxy options but I couldn't figure out which ones. Does anybody know how I can exclude `192.168.1.106` address?

Answer (score 1):

According to the official [documentation](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/network-settings#TOC-Command-line-options-for-proxy-settings) it's

```
--proxy-bypass-list=(<trailing_domain>|<ip-address>)[:<port>][;...]
```

So it should be

```
--proxy-bypass-list=192.168.1.106:4004
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but didn't work: `/usr/bin/chromium-browser --proxy-server="socks5://127.0.0.1:9050" --host-resolver-rules="MAP * ~NOTFOUND, EXCLUDE 127.0.0.1" --proxy-bypass-list="192.168.1.106:4004" 2>&1 > /dev/null &`